# Google fonts, how to include multiple subsets for multiple fonts?

Tags: google-font-api

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300|PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

For "PT Sans" cyrillic and latin works fine this way, but for "Open Sans" not. If i add to "Open Sans" subset value:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300&subset=latin,cyrillic|PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Both "PT Sans" and "Open Sans" fonts not working at all. What i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should work: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300|PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic

Answer (score 0):

This is probably counter intuitive, but if you're experiencing this problem, then linking to those fonts separately might do the trick. So instead of:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300|PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

you could use:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This is probably a bug in the Google Fonts API, but oddly enough it doesn't seem to affect Chrome.